# what does 'computeU' mean in computeSVD() function spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, svd

i found a code that uses  `computeSVD()` function ,here is the code

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
rows = sc.parallelize([
    Vectors.sparse(5, {1: 1.0, 3: 7.0}),
    Vectors.dense(2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
    Vectors.dense(4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0)
])
mat = RowMatrix(rows)
# Compute the top 5 singular values and corresponding singular vectors.
svd = mat.computeSVD(5, computeU=True)
U = svd.U       # The U factor is a RowMatrix.
s = svd.s       # The singular values are stored in a local dense vector.
V = svd.V       # The V factor is a local dense matrix.
```

what does `computeU=True` mean in this code ?

Comment: It denotes whether to calculate the U  matrix  or not (MATnxp= Unxn Snxp V^{T}pxp) - and the U matrix is what you print with svd.U)

Comment: does it change anything if we don't calculate the U matrix ?